# How to test the web service inside the docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-swarm

I am now testing the availability of the web service which is a Java Spring Boot program. When I run it locally and using curl to get response, it will show the status code whatever success or not:

```
curl -I localhost:8080/xxx
```

Returned result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2021 11:49:57 GMT
```

But when I try to test it in docker swarm, it keeps can't access the web service form outside, currently I only can test the web service inside the container:

```
docker exec -it [ID] /bin/sh
curl -I localhost:8080/xxx

HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 01 Feb 2021 11:53:07 GMT
```

Here is my docker command which used to init the swarm:

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr=127.0.0.1 --listen-addr 127.0.0.1

docker service create --replicas 1 -p 8088:8080 --name webtest --mount source=afdiavol,target=/ia_ai_ms bility/aia:2.0.3.6t
```

Does anyone know how to curl the web service inside the docker swarm?

Comment: What command are you running to make the request?  What does it return?  These details generally need to be in the question itself, not behind links, and as plain text, not as images.

Comment: @DavidMaze I just edit my post, you can take a look. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In your docker swarm init command you set the listen and advertise addresses as your loopback interface's address. You can try the broadcast address 0.0.0.0 for your deployment.

```
docker swarm init --advertise-addr=0.0.0.0 --listen-addr 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Tried, but it occur error :
Error response from daemon: advertise address must be a non-zero IP address or network interface (with optional port number)